# Only highlight keyword if surrounded by whitespace

Tags: listings, lstdefinestyle

I defined a language as follows:

```
\lstdefinelanguage{Z80}{
  sensitive = true,
  keywords={a, hl, h, l, b, c, e, ix, sp, bc, af, d},
  keywords = [2]{push, ld, and, pop, ret, sra, call, sla,
  cp, jp, sub, inc, require, or, out, in, dec, add, cpl, jr, z, nz, bit, ccf, scf},
  keywords = [3]{.include, .end, .text, equ, .data, db},
  alsoletter={.},
  keywordstyle=\color{red}\bfseries,
  keywordstyle=[2]{\color{blue}\bfseries}, 
  keywordstyle=[3]{\color{dkred}\bfseries},
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\scriptsize,
  stepnumber=1,
  numbersep=8pt,
  showstringspaces=false,
  breaklines=true,
  frame=tb,
  comment=[l]{;},
  morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
  commentstyle=\bfseries\color{dkgreen}\ttfamily,
  stringstyle=\color{dkred}\ttfamily,
  morestring=[b]',
  morestring=[b]",
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  backgroundcolor=\color{white}
}
```

The problem is that in some parts of the code I want to highlight, there are decimal numbers written followed by a "d", which is a keyword. For example the number nine is written as: "9d". Thus, the lstling is highlighting the "d" although in this case it should not.

I am a noob, so I don't understand why it would highlight "d" in this case, and not highlight other letters which are also keywords (say "a") inside other words.

Example:

[image: "a" is not highlighted inside word "entradaDATA" but "d" is highlighted in "0d"]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thank you @Mensch :) any idea of what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by doing:

```
alsoletter={. 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9},
```

Hope this helps somebody.